# Installing rosbridge indigo on OSX

Tags: ros, rosbridge-suite, ros-indigo, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
brew install ros-indigo-rosbridge-suite
```

Errors with "no available formulae"
Is there a way to bring up rosbridge on OSX (yosemite) ?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220901/installing-rosbridge-indigo-on-osx/) by [Fry](https://answers.ros.org/users/25033/fry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2015-11-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no Homebrew formula for ROS packages. You'll have to download the source and build it yourself.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0